# Richfaces 4 dynamic select options when user type

Tags: select, dynamic, richfaces

I am using rich faces select component.
I want dynamic values when user manually type some thing in the select component.

```
<rich:select enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="start typing for select" value="#{supplierSearchBean.userInput}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" listener="#{supplierSearchBean.userInputChange}"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{supplierSearchBean.selectOptions}" />
                        </rich:select>
```

Java code as follows

```
public void userInputChange(ActionEvent  ae){
       Map map = ae.getComponent().getAttributes();
       System.out.println(map.toString());

   }


 public void setUserInput(String userInput) {
       System.out.println("userINput = " + userInput);
       this.userInput = userInput;
   }
```

Here i found 2 issues
1st: setUserINput always print empty string when user type value
2nd: listener method never get call.

any help ?

Comment: U want to update the value on server on each keyup or on focus lost from d box...???

Comment: Check if the submitting portion is in <h:form> tag bcz then only it will submit the form and update the server and page..

Comment: Yes it is already in h:form tag

Comment: I found that a4j:ajax works with rich:select but will not udpate value on server side on every keyup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably that there is no selected value while the user types, and this component restricts the allowed values to the specified select items. A partial input is thus not valid and cannot be bound to your bean.

I think you could get the expected behavior if you use a `rich:autocomplete` instead. However, if you want to restrict the allowed values, maybe you can keep your `rich:select` and listen for the `selectitem` event.

Comment: I'm late here, but would listening for selectitem not fire until after something from the (initially empty) list have been selected? Can we somehow leverage EL2.2 to pass the currently typed string into the a4j:ajax listener (maybe on the listkeypress event)? Something like <a4j:ajax event="listkeypress" execute="@none" render="@this" listener="#{suggestBean.withPrefix(rich:element('myselect').value)}" />
Mind you, this is speculating until i get back to my codebase.

Comment: Hi @mabi, I have not been working with JSF and RF since I posted this answer so I won't be able to help you much. I think the simplest solution remains to use `rich:autocomplete` which does not restrict user input, hence you would be able to get it bound to your bean on keyup.

Comment: Thing is `rich:autocomplete` only gets `String` values as it's a pure `<input/>` field - if you can't use a converter (eg because the shown string doesn't identify the object uniquely) you're left with awful hacks like also setting the object-id in a hidden field or something.

Answer (score 0):

Override `getItems` function in `richfaces-utils.js` file in `richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar` under `richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final\META-INF\resources` folder.

Change the condition of pushing items to be

```
if(p != -1)
```

instead of

```
if(p == 0)
```

This should fix the issue.